# multiple sub-domains for same magento shop

Tags: magento

On our development server, I have a Magento shop that is shared with a couple of other developers who have got different url's but pointing on same database.

For example developer1 will have `http://dev1.magshop.com` dev2 will have `http://dev2.magshop.com` etc.
They all push their work with GIT.

The problem I have is that when I go on `http://dev2.magshop.com` it throws me back to `http://dev1.magshop.com` (that I configured first)

I would like to have everybody staying on his own URL. How can I do it? I saw a lot of tutorials how to add a second shop or a second url, but it's for other reasons that don't fit my needs.

Thanks to the World.

==== EDIT ====
Finally to achieve this the simple way was to leave {{base_url}} in development... I don't even know why I changed this, and made it so complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but afaik it's *impossible* to achieve what you want.

Magento uses the `web/unsecure/base_url` configured in the `core_config_data` database table to generate all its URLs for a given scope.

That means, even if you copy your Magento code to another (sub)domain to separate your developers codewise, they still all connect to a database which is configured to use `http://dev1.magshop.com` as base URL.

That said, to have everybody stay on his own URL, you'd need to setup one database per developer. Or to completely redesign Magento's `base_url` handling (not recommended).

Comment: I was working on the base_url in the core code, I was able to configure it, but still got a few problems.